# JOptionPane and getting text from input

Tags: java, string, swing, joptionpane

I have created a button that opens a `JOptionPane`. It allows the user to input a `string..>>  String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog`  How do I get the text that the user inputs into the joptionpane and use it to search through userobjects?

Many thanks

Comment: how did you stored the userobjects?

Answer (score 6):

The returned String is what the user entered, or null if the user chose to cancel:

```
String whatTheUserEntered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
if (whatTheUserEntered == null) {
    System.out.println("The user canceled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @JB Nizet already gave a good answer. I would like to add a short code example just for reference if someone comes looking for this problem again.

```
public class JOptionPaneExample
```

{
    private double price;

```
private JTextField priceField;

private JLabel priceLabel;

public JOptionPaneExample()
{
    priceField = new JTextField(10);
}

public void createAndDisplayGUI()
{
    int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, getPanel(), "Price Form : ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
    {
        price = Double.valueOf(priceField.getText());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Price is : " + Double.toString(price), "Price : ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (selection == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}

private JPanel getPanel()
{
    JPanel basePanel = new JPanel();
    basePanel.setOpaque(true);
    basePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
    centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    priceLabel = new JLabel("Enter Price : ");

    centerPanel.add(priceLabel);
    centerPanel.add(priceField);

    basePanel.add(centerPanel);

    return basePanel;
}
```

}

The same code can be found [this blog](http://pallandri.blogspot.com/2014/02/java-joptionpane-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose it a bit unclear, but from how I understand it you just want to know how to the info entered, this can be done by simply calling the variable.

To see what is in the variable, use System.out.println(variable name);

Please define userobjects?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

```
import javax.swing.*;  
public class OptionPaneExample {

    JFrame f;

    OptionPaneExample() {
        f = new JFrame();
        String userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f, "User Input Here:");
        //condition check
        if (userinput.equals("your condition here!"){
             System.out.println("your output!")
        } else {
             //do something
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OptionPaneExample();
    }
}
```

I found some useful `JOptionPane` examples with source codes. I think it will help you...

Link : [Java JOptionPane](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-joptionpane)